# How to escape # in PHP

Tags: php, escaping

How can I escape the **#** in PHP? When I use it in a query it turns the remaining line of code into a comment. This is what I have right now:

```
$columns = "head1, #_search, #_stuff";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $columns from table LIMIT $k,$j");
```

I can't just put escape **#** right after `$columns` since it will just become a comment.

~edit: yes I probably should have copied the code directly, but some of it is confidential and much more complicated.

Comment: This cannot compile. I suggest copy-and-pasting the code you're _actually_ trying to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following ? :

```
$columns = "head1, `#_search`, `#_stuff`";
```

You can use `(backtick) to quote reserved words.

If you want to quote table/column name you can do the following example:

```
 SELECT * FROM `#table1` WHERE `#table1`.`#column1` = 1;
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `quotes` for your strings:

```
$columns = 'head1, #_search, #_stuff';
```

However, this still doesn't make much sense.

It's also recommended to favour `PDO` or  `mysqli` over `mysql_*`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding backslashes

```
$columns = 'head1, \#_search, \#_stuff';
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be a string literal?

```
$columns = 'head1, #_search, #_stuff'
```